# CGO не видит методы

Tags: golang

Использую C-библиотеку под Golang с помощью cgo.

При подлючении .c файла - изначально проблем нет, методы можно использовать. Но при попытке вызова Go-функции из Си-кода, компилятор ругается на то, что методы уже объявлены ранее.

Ок, подключаем .h файл вместо .c - компилятор ругается: `undefined reference to "func name"`

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Исходный код:

```
    package main

/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -std=c99 -I .
#cgo LDFLAGS: -lws2_32
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "open62541.h"

extern void callback();
static void answer() {
    callback();
}
*/
import "C"
import "fmt"

func main() {
    const url = "opc.tcp://127.0.0.1:49320"
    const node = "Channel1.Device1.Tag1"

    var client = C.UA_Client_new(C.UA_ClientConfig_standard)
    var connect = C.UA_Client_connect(client, C.CString(url))

    var subId C.UA_UInt32 = 0
    C.UA_Client_Subscriptions_new(client, C.UA_SubscriptionSettings_standard, &subId)

    var monitorThis = C.UA_NODEID_STRING(2, C.CString(node));
    var monId C.UA_UInt32 = 0
    C.UA_Client_Subscriptions_addMonitoredItem(client, subId, monitorThis, C.UA_ATTRIBUTEID_VALUE,
        C.answer, nil, &monId);

    C.UA_Client_Subscriptions_manuallySendPublishRequest(client);
}

//export callback
func callback() {
    fmt.Println("answer!")
}
```

Код ошибки:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build666103966\command-line-arguments\_obj\_cgo_main.o:_cgo_main.c:(.data+0x0): undefined reference to `answer'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build666103966\command-line-arguments\_obj\_cgo_main.o:_cgo_main.c:(.data+0x8): undefined reference to `UA_SubscriptionSettings_standard'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build666103966\command-line-arguments\_obj\_cgo_main.o:_cgo_main.c:(.data+0x10): undefined reference to `UA_ClientConfig_standard'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build666103966\command-line-arguments\_obj\main.cgo2.o: In function `_cgo_4547f9bb4959_Cfunc_UA_Client_Subscriptions_addMonitoredItem':
./cgo-gcc-prolog:47: undefined reference to `UA_Client_Subscriptions_addMonitoredItem'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build666103966\command-line-arguments\_obj\main.cgo2.o: In function `_cgo_4547f9bb4959_Cfunc_UA_Client_Subscriptions_manuallySendPublishRequest':
./cgo-gcc-prolog:65: undefined reference to `UA_Client_Subscriptions_manuallySendPublishRequest'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build666103966\command-line-arguments\_obj\main.cgo2.o: In function `_cgo_4547f9bb4959_Cfunc_UA_Client_Subscriptions_new':
./cgo-gcc-prolog:85: undefined reference to `UA_Client_Subscriptions_new'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build666103966\command-line-arguments\_obj\main.cgo2.o: In function `_cgo_4547f9bb4959_Cfunc_UA_Client_connect':
./cgo-gcc-prolog:104: undefined reference to `UA_Client_connect'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build666103966\command-line-arguments\_obj\main.cgo2.o: In function `_cgo_4547f9bb4959_Cfunc_UA_Client_new':
./cgo-gcc-prolog:121: undefined reference to `UA_Client_new'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что было использована команда 
`go build main.go`
Команда `go build` в корне проекта решила проблему.

В Gogland необходимо настроить конфигурация запуска с файла на пакет и указать пакет приложения.